# How print more than one page in VB?

Tags: vb.net

What should I change in my code to see more than one page in Print preview and also print more than one page?

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDoc.PrintPage
    Static intStart As Integer
    Dim font0 As New Font("arial", 24, FontStyle.Underline)
    Dim fntText As Font = font0
    Dim txtHeight As Integer
    Dim LeftMargin As Integer = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
    Dim TopMargin As Integer = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top
    txtHeight = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top - PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom

    Dim LinesPerPage As Integer = CInt(Math.Round(txtHeight / (fntText.Height + 0.025)))


    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, e.MarginBounds)
    Dim intLineNumber As Integer
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Support", font0, Brushes.Black, 75, 50)
    For intCounter = intStart To lstLinesToPrint.Count - 1

        e.Graphics.DrawString(lstLinesToPrint(intCounter), fntText, Brushes.Black, LeftMargin, fntText.Height * intLineNumber + TopMargin)
        intLineNumber += 1
        If intLineNumber > LinesPerPage - 1 Then
            intStart = intCounter
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like the code has been written to output a single page at a time. To output the second page, you would need to call the function a second time.

Comment: @RPM That's what the `e.HasMorePages = True` should cause to happen.

Comment: It already does.  But it has a bug, it can only work once.  You must move the intStart variable out of the method so it becomes a field of the class.  And you need to handle the BeginPrint event to reset the variable back to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is, your code *does* print more than one page... providing it has the other code needed to feed it.

I put two buttons on a Form, bnPrint and bnPreview, and created some data to test with:

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Form1

    Enum PrintOperation
        Print
        Preview
    End Enum

    Dim pageSetupDialog1 As PageSetupDialog
    Dim pd As PrintDocument
    Dim selectedPrinter As String

    Dim lstLinesToPrint As New List(Of String)

    Sub PrintDoc(operation As PrintOperation)

        Try
            pd = New PrintDocument()

            pageSetupDialog1 = New PageSetupDialog
            pageSetupDialog1.PageSettings = New PageSettings

            ' initialize dialog's PrinterSettings property to hold user-set printer settings.
            pageSetupDialog1.PrinterSettings = New PrinterSettings

            pageSetupDialog1.AllowMargins = True
            pageSetupDialog1.ShowNetwork = True

            If selectedPrinter <> "" Then
                pageSetupDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = selectedPrinter
            End If

            Dim result As DialogResult = pageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog()

            If result = DialogResult.OK Then
                selectedPrinter = pageSetupDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
                AddHandler pd.BeginPrint, AddressOf pd_BeginPrint
                AddHandler pd.QueryPageSettings, AddressOf pd_QueryPageSettings
                AddHandler pd.PrintPage, AddressOf pd_PrintPage

                Try
                    If operation = PrintOperation.Print Then
                        pd.Print()
                    Else
                        Using ppd As New PrintPreviewDialog
                            ppd.Document = pd
                            ppd.ShowDialog()
                        End Using
                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Oops: " & ex.Message)

                Finally
                    RemoveHandler pd.BeginPrint, AddressOf pd_BeginPrint
                    RemoveHandler pd.QueryPageSettings, AddressOf pd_QueryPageSettings
                    RemoveHandler pd.PrintPage, AddressOf pd_PrintPage
                End Try

            End If

        Finally
            pageSetupDialog1.Dispose()
            pd.Dispose()

        End Try

    End Sub

    Sub pd_BeginPrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ev As PrintEventArgs)
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = selectedPrinter
        pd.DocumentName = "Test document"
    End Sub

    Sub pd_QueryPageSettings(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.QueryPageSettingsEventArgs)
        ' make sure the orientation is set /before/ it gets to pd_PrintPage
        e.PageSettings.Landscape = pageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.Landscape
    End Sub

    Private Sub pd_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
        Static intStart As Integer

        Using font0 As New Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Underline), fntText As Font = font0

            Dim LeftMargin As Integer = pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
            Dim TopMargin As Integer = pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top
            Dim txtHeight = pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top - pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom

            Dim LinesPerPage As Integer = CInt(Math.Round(txtHeight / (fntText.Height + 0.025)))

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, e.MarginBounds)
            Dim intLineNumber As Integer
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Support", font0, Brushes.Black, 75, 50)

            For intCounter = intStart To lstLinesToPrint.Count - 1
                e.Graphics.DrawString(lstLinesToPrint(intCounter), fntText, Brushes.Black, LeftMargin, fntText.Height * intLineNumber + TopMargin)
                intLineNumber += 1

                If intLineNumber > LinesPerPage - 1 Then
                    intStart = intCounter
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next

        End Using


        If Not e.HasMorePages Then
            ' reset in case the user does a preview then a print etc.
            intStart = 0
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub bnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnPrint.Click
        PrintDoc(PrintOperation.Print)

    End Sub

    Private Sub bnPreview_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnPreview.Click
        PrintDoc(PrintOperation.Preview)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Create some test data...
        For i = 1 To 100
            lstLinesToPrint.Add("Line" & i)
        Next

    End Sub


End Class
```

I made some adjustments to your code: fonts need to have .Dispose() called on them to free-up system resources when you've finished using them - this is taken care of by the [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) construct. I could have put more Using statements in there, but I used the Finally clause of a Try instead sometimes. I changed the name of `PrintDoc` as that was already the name of the method I copied from some other program I had to hand.

If you wanted to keep the possibility of printing in landscape format, note that  if printing landscape, the margins are as expected (left is left etc.) but the width and height are the wrong way round. I did not change the code shown to take that into account.

Sample output of the last page of the print preview:

[image: Print preview dialog]

Comment: @DanielPelka Just out of interest, was there any particular part of the code which helped?

Comment: Nope, I used whole code. Now I enlarge my program (this is engineering calculator for bridge support design) and I print whole document in Form1_load like:

lstLinesToPrint1.Add(" -wymiar pilastra b0=" + CStr(b0) + "m") lstLinesToPrint1.Add(" -wymiar Bprim=" + CStr(Bprim) + "m")

And now my problem is that if you change in calculator any variable (like b0 or Bprim) in preview print or print i don't see this change.

Comment: @DanielPełka It's best not to put code directly in Form1_load (sometimes exceptions don't get raised from there), instead put it in a separate sub and call that from Form1_load. Then, if you need to run the code again, you can just call the sub.

Comment: In last sentence you mean call the sub form1_load?

Comment: @DanielPełka No, the separate sub.

Comment: Yea, it works, but now if i click x*times button calculate which calls this separate sub i have x*pages to print. I know that i have to in beggining in separate sub clean earlier text but which command i have tu use?

Comment: @DanielPełka I think that is different enough from this question to need a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254104/which-command-i-have-to-use-to-clear-the-text-in-printpreview-in-vb