# Which command i have to use to clear the text in PrintPreview in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I have function text which adds text to Print Preview by code:

```
name.add("Name is "+cstr(name)+ " ")
```

I call this function text in my function add.
Problem is that if i want change name in textbox then click add I see more than one line in Print Preview (number of lines are equal to amount of clicks add)
Which command i have to use in beginning of function text to clear earlier lines?

Comment: What is the type of `name`? If it is a List then you can use [`name.Clear()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2). (I guess it's just a typo that there appears to be two different variables named "name".)

Comment: It works, thanks :)